# Is there a better way to add const functions to an javascript object?

Tags: javascript, constants, javascript-objects

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
var myObject = {}

const action = () => {
    console.log("say hello")
}

myObject.act = action
```

This results in the output:

```
say hello
```

But is there a faster way to do this, like a const lambda (or something)?

Much like:

```
// This is psuedocode.
myObject.myConstAction = const lambda (){
    console.log("I won't change.")
}
```

I would hope the property `.myConstAction` cannot be reassigned or overwritten.

Comment: To make a constant function property, you have to use `Object.defineProperty(myObject, "act", {writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false, value: () => console.log("say hello")});`. `const` doesn’t help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaken in what the code you have does.

`action` is a constant, and its value cannot be changed.

`myObject.act` is assigned a *copy* of the value of `action` (i.e. another reference to the same function). There is nothing constant about `myObject.act`.

---

You can assign a function to `act` and make the property read only like so:

```js
var myObject = {}
Object.defineProperty(myObject, "act", {
  value: action = () => {
    console.log("say hello");
  },
  writable: false
});

myObject.act();
// The next line has no effect because the property is not writable
myObject.act = () => console.log("Overwritten!");
myObject.act();
```

Comment: Also, add `configurable: false` to prohibit overwriting `myObject.act` with another `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: @Quentin this is exactly what I was looking for. But can you add `configurable: false` to your answer or explain why you wouldn't need it or want it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's not really any such thing as a "const function" (or a const *anything*) that's a *property* of an object. The quickest way is still

`myObject.act = () => console.log('say hello');`

See how the `const` identifier doesn't really do anything:

```js
const myObject = {}
const action = () => {
    console.log("say hello")
}
myObject.act = action;


myObject.act = () => console.log('goodbye');
myObject.act();
```

Comment: So a `const` object can have variable properties?

Comment: Reassignment and mutation are completely different concepts. `const` means that the variable name on the left-hand side of the `=` can never be reassigned - and that's all.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 To make an object non-mutable (its own properties, but not nested properties), apply [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to it.

Comment: @Xufox that you for that very useful link about `Object.freeze`

Comment: I think this answer demonstrates the limits of `const` effectively.